# IllegalStateException: The mapped controller method class XXX is not an instance of the actual controller bean instance 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55'

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm studying Spring and Hibernate. Faced the following error

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: getCriteriaBuilder is not valid without active transaction

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: getCriteriaBuilder is not valid without active transaction
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: getCriteriaBuilder is not valid without active transaction
    org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.getCriteriaBuilder(Unknown Source)
    eventOrganizer.dao.impl.DBEventImpl.getEvent(DBEventImpl.java:41)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

The exception associated with the transaction. I tried to use a transaction with an annotation. I also tried to open transactions in the code itself. The result is the same: exception

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>EventOrganizer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <webflow-version>2.4.1.RELEASE</webflow-version>
    <spring-framework-version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring-framework-version>
    <springsecurity-version>3.2.6.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
    <slf4j-version>1.6.1</slf4j-version>
    <mojarra-version>2.2.10</mojarra-version>
    <primefaces-version>5.1</primefaces-version>
    <hibernate-version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate-version>
    <mysqlconnector-version>5.1.37</mysqlconnector-version>
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>


    <!--Spring-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--Hibernate and MySQL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysqlconnector-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aspectj/aspectjrt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**web.xml:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventorganizer</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <mapping resource="eventOrganizer/entities/Client.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="eventOrganizer/entities/Event.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="eventOrganizer/entities/GenreEvent.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="eventOrganizer/entities/PlaceEvent.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="eventOrganizer/entities/User.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="eventOrganizer"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="msg" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/locales/messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="localResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="ru"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**DBEventImpl:**

```
package eventOrganizer.dao.impl;

import eventOrganizer.dao.interfaces.EventDAO;
import eventOrganizer.entities.Client;
import eventOrganizer.entities.Event;
import eventOrganizer.entities.GenreEvent;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;

@Repository
@RequestMapping(value = "/event")

@Transactional
public class DBEventImpl implements EventDAO {
    public DBEventImpl() {
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private List<Event> events;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = GET)
    @Override
    public List<Event> getEvent() {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Event.class);
        Root<Event> root = criteriaQuery.from(Event.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root);
        Query query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        events = query.getResultList();

        return events;
    }

    public List<Event> getEvent(Client client) {
        return null;
    }

    public List<Event> getEvent(String eventName) {
        return null;
    }

    public List<Event> getEvent(GenreEvent genreEvent) {
        return null;
    }

    public List<Event> getEvent(Character letter) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Event:**

```
package eventOrganizer.entities;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Event {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int genreId;
    private int clientId;
    private int placeId;
    private Timestamp date;
    private Timestamp timeBegin;
    private Timestamp timeDuration;
    private String source;
    private byte[] image;
    private String description;
    private Integer rating;
    private String voteCount;
    private byte[] content;

    public Event() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getGenreId() {
        return genreId;
    }

    public void setGenreId(int genreId) {
        this.genreId = genreId;
    }

    public int getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(int clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public int getPlaceId() {
        return placeId;
    }

    public void setPlaceId(int placeId) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
    }

    public Timestamp getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimeBegin() {
        return timeBegin;
    }

    public void setTimeBegin(Timestamp timeBegin) {
        this.timeBegin = timeBegin;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimeDuration() {
        return timeDuration;
    }

    public void setTimeDuration(Timestamp timeDuration) {
        this.timeDuration = timeDuration;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(Integer rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(String voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Event event = (Event) o;

        if (id != event.id) return false;
        if (genreId != event.genreId) return false;
        if (clientId != event.clientId) return false;
        if (placeId != event.placeId) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(event.name) : event.name != null) return false;
        if (date != null ? !date.equals(event.date) : event.date != null) return false;
        if (timeBegin != null ? !timeBegin.equals(event.timeBegin) : event.timeBegin != null) return false;
        if (timeDuration != null ? !timeDuration.equals(event.timeDuration) : event.timeDuration != null) return false;
        if (source != null ? !source.equals(event.source) : event.source != null) return false;
        if (!Arrays.equals(image, event.image)) return false;
        if (description != null ? !description.equals(event.description) : event.description != null) return false;
        if (rating != null ? !rating.equals(event.rating) : event.rating != null) return false;
        if (voteCount != null ? !voteCount.equals(event.voteCount) : event.voteCount != null) return false;
        if (!Arrays.equals(content, event.content)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + genreId;
        result = 31 * result + clientId;
        result = 31 * result + placeId;
        result = 31 * result + (date != null ? date.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (timeBegin != null ? timeBegin.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (timeDuration != null ? timeDuration.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (source != null ? source.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + Arrays.hashCode(image);
        result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (rating != null ? rating.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (voteCount != null ? voteCount.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + Arrays.hashCode(content);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Event.hbm.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="eventOrganizer.entities.Event" table="event" schema="eventorganizer">
        <id name="id" column="id"/>
        <property name="name" column="name"/>
        <property name="genreId" column="genre_id"/>
        <property name="clientId" column="client_id"/>
        <property name="placeId" column="place_id"/>
        <property name="date" column="date"/>
        <property name="timeBegin" column="timeBegin"/>
        <property name="timeDuration" column="timeDuration"/>
        <property name="source" column="source"/>
        <property name="image" column="image"/>
        <property name="description" column="description"/>
        <property name="rating" column="rating"/>
        <property name="voteCount" column="voteCount"/>
        <property name="content" column="content"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am asking to help me with this Exception

Comment: Remove `hibernate.current_session_context_class` from your configuration, that breaks proper tx setup/integration with spring.

Comment: @m-deinum Спасибо. Когда я удаляю эту строку, я получаю другое исключение: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Не удалось получить транзакционную синхронизацию Сессия для текущего потока